# Inaccessible SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn

I have a problem accessing my SVN repository. After re-booting my Linux host, my SVN repositories on that host are in-accessible. Although I can create new repositories on that host with the `svnadmin create` command, the newly created repositories are still not accessible. In the configuration file of the repository I have enabled Read/Write for anonymous access, but this doesn't seem to help.

What could be the problem? If SVN needs to be restarted or something, how do I do that safely?

Comment: This is not coding related, should be on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: How did you access your repo before? Using `svn://host/`, `http://host` (or `https://host`), `svn+ssh://host/` ..?

Comment: @Chris - Instead of making fun of the poster's (likely non-native) English, why didn't you just correct the question instead?

Comment: @Mike Swift - And what would you like to do with the other 8263 questions tagged `svn`? This is a version control system *for programmers*!

Comment: I was accessing the svn repository from Eclipse by adding the repository url svn://host/path-to-repo

Comment: @acoolguy: Since it happened after reboot, have you check if svn is running? Also what's the file permissions on the new repos? Does the svn user have read/write access?

Comment: Yes the svn user has read/write access. I had changed the configuration to allow anonymous accesss for Read/Write.